# using python pandas i want to normalize data frame column on non null values

Tags: python, pandas, normalize

I have one data frame and i am reading that with pandas python , in that one column contains dictonay values and i want to normalize that column i.e i want to split and i am using this:

```
if 'X' in df_cols:
    def only_dict(d):
    '''
    Convert json string representation of dictionary to a 
python dict
'''
return d

A = json_normalize(df['X'].apply(only_dict).tolist()).add_prefix('X.')
df = df.drop('X', axis=1).join(A)
```

but this column contains some null values too, so i want to apply only on column which have not null values using labmda is anyone have idea how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just a code example. You can call to your own function using apply and lambda functions. You can access any column in your df using the parameter "axis=1". You con store the result of any transformation in a new column returning the desired value in the function and storing it in a new column.

def your_function(row):
    if row[your_column]:
        return row[your_column].split()
   else:
       return None

df['new_column'] = pandas.apply(lambda row: your_function(row),axis=1)